# Google Cloud Platform launch multiple instances with InstanceGroupManager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to launch multiple instances from Google Cloud Platform with [InstanceGroupManager](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances) via Java API. The order I following is

1. Create an [Instance Template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates)
2. Create an Instance Group Manager with given Instance Template

As far as I understand, if I need to create multiple instances then I need to create equivalent number of disks where each of them will be assigned to each instance created. The problem is I create equivalent number of disks and then create `InstanceTemplate` with them. However, when I create instances with InstanceGroupManager second instance always fail due to `The disk resource XXX is already being used by instance-ABC`. So, what I see if I create two disks (one is boot disk and other is not) two disks get attached to the first instance so that second instance won't get any disks.

I tried to simplify the java code that I am running here. You can see the way I am creating `InstanceTemplate`, `InstanceGroupManager` and executing it.

```java
    private void launchInstances(String instanceData, int instanceCount) GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Compute gcpClient = createGCPClient();
        String image = "projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-1804-lts";
        String securityGroup = "global/networks/default";
        String instanceType = "n1-highcpu-4";

        // create instance template
        InstanceTemplate instanceTemplate = new InstanceTemplate();
        String templateUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        instanceTemplate.setName("test-template-" + templateUUID);
        instanceTemplate.setProperties(buildInstanceProperties(instanceData, cloudRegionEntity, count));
        Operation createIntanceTemplateOp = gcpClient.instanceTemplates().insert("test-project", instanceTemplate).execute();

        // create instance group manager
        InstanceGroupManager instanceGroupManager = new InstanceGroupManager();
        InstanceGroupManagerVersion version = new InstanceGroupManagerVersion();
        version.setInstanceTemplate("global/instanceTemplates/" + instanceTemplate.getName());
        instanceGroupManager.setVersions(Collections.singletonList(version));
        instanceGroupManager.setTargetSize(count);
        instanceGroupManager.setName("intance-group-manager" + templateUUID);

        String zone = "us-west2-a"
        Operation launchInsGrOp = zone; gcpClient.instanceGroupManagers().insert("test-project", zone, instanceGroupManager).execute();
        launchInsGrOp = gcpClient.zoneOperations().get("test-project", zone, operation.getName()).execute();

    }

    private InstanceProperties buildInstanceProperties(String instanceData, String image, int instanceCount) {
        InstanceProperties instanceProperties = new InstanceProperties();

        // set disk properties
        instanceProperties.setDisks(buildAttachedDisk(image, instanceCount));

        // set metadata properties
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Metadata.Items item = new Metadata.Items();
        item.setKey("startup-script");
        item.setValue(instanceData);
        metadata.setItems(Collections.singletonList(item));
        instanceProperties.setMetadata(metadata);

        // set machine-type property
        instanceProperties.setMachineType("n1-highcpu-4");

        // set network-interface property
        instanceProperties.setNetworkInterfaces(Collections.singletonList(buildNetworkInterface("global/networks/default")));

        // build service account property
        instanceProperties.setServiceAccounts(Collections.singletonList(buildServiceAccount()));
        return instanceProperties;
    }

    private List<AttachedDisk> buildAttachedDisk(String machineType, int count) {
        List<AttachedDisk> attachedDisks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int ind = 0; ind < count; ind++) {
            // Add attached Persistent Disk to be used by VM Instance.
            AttachedDisk attachedDisk = new AttachedDisk();
            attachedDisk.setAutoDelete(true);
            if (ind == 0) {
                attachedDisk.setBoot(true);
            } else {
                attachedDisk.setBoot(false);
            }
            attachedDisk.setType("PERSISTENT");
            AttachedDiskInitializeParams params = new AttachedDiskInitializeParams();
            params.setDiskName("test-disk-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            // Specify the source operating system machine image to be used by the VM Instance.
            params.setSourceImage(machineType);
            attachedDisk.setInitializeParams(params);

            attachedDisks.add(attachedDisk);
        }

        return attachedDisks;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using [regional instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/distributing-instances-with-regional-instance-groups). Basically, using `gcpClient.regionInstanceGroupManagers().insert("test-project", "us-west2", instanceGroupManager).execute();` solved the issue.